# jpGraph vs pGraph

Tags: php, graphics, graph

I have been using pGraph in the past, but the most recent version keeps on throwing errors. So I figured it was time consider alternatives.
I had a look at the jpGraph library which looks quite interesting, even though I'm only looking at simple line charts.

Any ideas and/or experiences? What are you guys using?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

There are other alternatives to jpGraph, though I tend to use that for some of the more esoteric chart types such as 3d terrain charts. Others I'd consider include: [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/cdphp.html), [GraPHPite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/), [LibChart](http://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/pages/introduction/) and [TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/overview.html)... all of which are more than capable or producing good looking line charts